# NetLogo time extension: Plotting graphs does not work?

Tags: time, netlogo

The time extensions seems to update the tick counter in the interface view, but not for the plots? I am using the `MousetrapDiscreteEvents.nlogo` file in the Examples folder of the the time extension.

Plotting graphs via right clicking the plot and adding the following line doesn't work:

```
plot count patches with [pcolor = yellow]
```

However, if written in code it does work, like the authoer of the time extensions demonstrates:

```
set-current-plot "Untriggered traps"
plotxy ticks count patches with [pcolor = yellow]
```

But why doesn't the first one work?

Comment: In what way does the first one not work? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the extension is doing the equivalent of `tick-advance` ([dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#tick-advance)), which does not trigger plot updates? If so, you might report it as a bug to the extension author.

But anyway, you can work around it by calling `update-plots` ([dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#update-plots)) yourself at the appropriate points in your code.